# How to import many ADT classes

Tags: scala

Suppose I defined an ADT in a source file `A.scala` like this:

```
package org.michael.foo

 sealed trait A extends Product with Serializable
 case class A1() extends A
 case class A2() extends A
 case class A3() extends A
 case class A4() extends A
 // etc., etc.
```

Now I would like to import all these classes `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4` etc. 
I am writing `import org.michael.foo.{A1, A2, A3, A4}` but what if I have a dozen of case classes to import ?

I can use `import org.michael.foo._` but I want to import *only* the ADT classes rather than all classes of `foo`.

What is the best way to import these ADT classes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the implementations into `A`'s companion object. This is a fairly common pattern:

```
package org.michael.foo

sealed trait A extends Product with Serializable
object A {
  case class A1() extends A
  case class A2() extends A
  case class A3() extends A
  case class A4() extends A
}

import org.michael.foo.A._
A3()
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `org.michael.foo._`
which is the equivalent of `org.michael.foo.*` in Java

Comment: Thanks. I just forgot to say I wanted to import _only_  the ADT classes but not all classes of `foo`. I will update the question.

Comment: Might not be exactly what you are looking for but it seems that you can hide some imports while importing the other one... It would allow you to give visibility to your ATDs and hide all the classes you want to hide. Please check https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Import#Hiding for more details

Comment: Did not know about the hiding. Interesting!